# $.getScript() in JQuery how this method exactly work

Tags: jquery

I need to make sure that how [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) JQuery method exactly work ,
is this method check for the script if it was loaded before load it agian or will load the external script each time I call the method.

I have tried to take a look on this method [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L23)

Answer (score 2):

From [the very documentation you linked to](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

By default, `$.getScript()` sets the cache setting to `false`. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to `ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested`. You can override this feature by setting the cache property globally using `$.ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```